# Libraries for static HTML site?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, static

I am building a completely static HTML site. I have been looking at libraries like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) or [Kirby](http://getkirby.com/). But, these libraries seem geared towards using dynamic content or CMS'able content that can be edited after logging in.

Can anyone recommend a good starting point for creating a completely static, non-editable, non-database HTML website?

Comment: Why does Bootstrap appear to be for CMS-y sites to you?

Comment: It doesn't, perhaps I phrased the question incorrectly. The point is that I'm looking for a good starting point to build a static HTML site without a CMS or other dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is not a CMS, bootstrap is a CSS framework, and has nothing to do with content.  [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a good framework as is [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).  Honestly these frameworks were intended for wireframing, and your better off writing the site on your own starting with a simple boiler plate like [HTML5BoilerPlate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).